# Mobile Design - 2 teir drop down search and footer menu (Like apple apps store)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first post as I've only joined up today. I'm a first year student, studying computer science. I'm looking for some advice on the below. Within one of the modules on our course, we are building a mobile website. I've designed my first page on microsoft powerpoint and I'm just about to start the implementation, However there are two sections I'm struggling to find out how to create. Please see the design below..

[image]

I would like to create a two tiered dropdown menu.. For example - the visitor selects the product they require, then selects the area they require the product in... i.e. PAT Testing - Dundee... they would then press search and be re-directed to the appropriate page.

How do I create the above? Any advice on the above would be greatly appreciated.

I would also like to create an apple app store footer menu but with my own icons. How do I insert my own icons?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Thanks Paulie, I appreciate your comment. I'll give it a go myself.